# Three-dimensional array efficient iteration

Tags: php, arrays

So, I have this array:

```
 $fields['field_user_name']['#required_error'] = 'Error text';
```

I have another array `$element`, which has to be populated like this:

```
if ($element['#field_name'] == 'field_user_name')){
  $element['#required_error'] = 'Error text';
}
```

Note that field names, error types and text are different in the array. Its a simple task, but Im looking for a most efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using:

```
    foreach ($fields as $field_name => $field_errors){
      if (isset($element['#field_name']) && $element['#field_name'] == $field_name){
        foreach ($field_errors as $error_type => $error_text){
          $element[$error_type] = $error_text;
        }
      }
    }
```